# Windows 2012 Clustering and Network adapter

Tags: windows, windows-cluster

I have a windows cluster (2012). Would like to ask, if I disable the network adapter to simulate a failure in network adapter, my current node should fail over to the other node. However, i didn't see the fail over happening. All my resources just stays "failed" and cluster role has stopped , instead of fail-overing..

What could be the cause?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for node failover due to network adapter fault was added in Windows Server 2012 R2.

See "Protected network" option in virtual machine settings, advanced features of network adapter.

This also applies for Hyper-V Server 2012 R2.